# Property on (bound) `this` is undefined - context issue?

Tags: javascript, this, dom-events

I am having a problem with the scope of my variable `currentRowIndex` in this `init` function. Within the `onclickevent` function, `this.currentRowIndex` is undefined. Can anyone see what the problem is with what I have done as I would expect it to work as I have used `.bind()` on the event handler.

```
 init: function() {

        this.getTable().addEventHandler("rowclick", function(row, model) {
                    this.currentRowIndex = row.element.element.rowIndex-1;
        }.bind(this));

        this.removeIcon = new Icon({
            onclickevent: function() {

          //this.currentRowIndex is undefined here(don't know why)
                this.getEventBus().publish("cell-link-clicked", this.currentRowIndex);
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
```

Comment: Maybe the icon is clicked before the row?

Comment: Thanks-you are right. The row should click if the icon is clicked but this isn't happening. It works if I click the row first and then the icon. I'll have to look into it some more. Thanks

Comment: Is the icon inside that row? Then yes, the event will bubble from the icon to the row. You might try the capturing phase of the event to set the `currentRowIndex`.

Comment: How does it work? O_o You use `bind` function incorrectly.

Comment: Yes the icon is inside the row. What I want is for the row to be selected when the icon is selected. Currently the way it is the row must be clicked and then an icon

Comment: And what is "rowclick" event?

Answer (score -2):

```
init: function() {
    var that = this;
        this.getTable().addEventHandler("rowclick", function(row, model) {
                    that.currentRowIndex = row.element.element.rowIndex-1;
        });

        this.removeIcon = new Icon({
            onclickevent: function() {

          //this.currentRowIndex is undefined here(don't know why)
                that.getEventBus().publish("cell-link-clicked", this.currentRowIndex);
            }
        });
    },
```

Comment: What difference does this make? What did you change, and why - please explain?

Comment: don't make people look for the differences, provide an explanation

Comment: Why are you still using `this.currentRowIndex`, which is almost surely wrong now?

Comment: You didn't change the part that is throwing the error. It is the second `this.currentRowIndex`, not the first, that the OP said is throwing an error.

Comment: Exception is beeing throwing in second part because first part has logical error